# Перекодирование koi-8 в cp1251

Tags: bash, cp1251

```
#!/bin/bash

function koiwin
{
num=( 30 00 01 22 04 05 20 03 21 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 \

15 31 16 17 18 19 06 02 28 27 07 24 29 25 23 26 )
for i in ${num[*]}; do
low=$low"\3$i"
up=$up"\3`expr $i + 40`"
done
echo $up$low

return
}

if test $# -lt 2
then echo "Usage: `basename $0` input.koi output.win table"; exit −7
fi

if ! test -f $1
then echo "$1: No such regular file" >&2; exit 2
fi

if ! test -f $3
then echo "$3: No such regular file" >&2; exit 2
fi

if ! test -r $1
then echo "$1: Permission denied to read" >&2; exit 13
fi

if ! test -r $3
then echo "$3: Permission denied to read" >&2; exit 13
fi

curdir=`pwd`
outdir=`expr $2 : '\(.*/\)' \| $curdir`

if [ ! -w $outdir -a ! -e $2 ]
then echo "$outdir: Permission denied to write" >&2; exit -13
fi

if test -d $2
then echo "$2: Is directory" >&2; exit 21
fi

if [ -e $2 -a ! -w $2 ]
then echo $2: Permission denied to rewrite; exit 13
fi

cat $1 | tr "\300-\337\340-\377" `koiwin` > $2

exit 0
```

сделал скрипт, на выход кракозябры, не понимаю почему

Comment: наверно, неправильно перекодируете. начиная с первого символа: `0300` должен быть заменён на `0376` (см. вывод `$ echo -ne '\0300' | iconv -f koi8r -t cp1251 | od`), а у вас он заменяется на `0370`

Comment: последовательность для `num`, вероятно, должна быть такой: `36 00 01 26 04 05 24 03 25 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 37 20 21 22 23 06 02 34 33 07 30 35 31 27 32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. вы неправильно перекодируете. последовательность должна быть такой:

   ```
   num=(36 00 01 26 04 05 24 03 25 10 11 12 13 14 15 \
   16 17 37 20 21 22 23 06 02 34 33 07 30 35 31 27 32)
   ```
2. вы упустили буквы `ёЁ`, которые в этих кодировках будут иметь такие восьмиричные коды:

   ```
   $ echo -n ёЁ | iconv -t koi8r | od -A n -b
    243 263
   $ echo -n ёЁ | iconv -t cp1251 | od -A n -b
    270 250
   ```

без лишнего мусора скрипт будет выглядеть, например, так:

```
#!/bin/bash

function koiwin {
  num=(36 00 01 26 04 05 24 03 25 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 \
  17 37 20 21 22 23 06 02 34 33 07 30 35 31 27 32)
  for i in ${num[*]}; do
    low="$low\3$i"
    up="$up\3$(expr $i + 40)"
  done
  # ёЁ
  up="\250$up"
  low="\270$low"
  echo $up$low
}

tr "\263\300-\337\243\340-\377" $(koiwin)
```

читает строку в кодировке *koi8r* из *stdin*, записывает строку в кодировке *cp1251* в *stdout*.